# NHibernate 3.3 or Entity Framework 4.3 for Oracle 11g and ASP.NET MVC 3.0?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I have to choose between last versions of NHibernate (3.3) and Entity Framework (4.3) to work with Oracle 11g; a very special issue with our architecture is: we have to execute a lot of stored procedures to keep balance with others old systems.

We're gonna use **ASP.NET MVC 3** for user interface. so, can you help to choose which is more convenient for our architecture between **NHibernate** and **Entity** **Framework**?

I have read that Oracle driver for Entity Framework is very new, so, I can't decide yet.

Comment: If the EF driver is very new, why would you consider it over NHibernate?

Comment: Microsoft seems very committed to EF, so I would expect an acceptable product.. actually, I haven't work with any of those before, so we're looking for the simplest to work with stored procedures.. thanks @PinnyM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS is very committed to EF but they are not developing provider for Oracle! Is Oracle committed to EF as well?

The best way to make decision is to create a short POC (proof of concept) where you evaluate both tools on some easy and intermediate problems (you can also try a hard problem) you will have to solve in the real project. This will help you understand challenges in both tools on your real problems not only in some imaginary discussion. It will also help you understand difficulties in adopting a new technology and integrating it with your existing environment.

Comment: thanks @LadislavMrnka, POC is the way to go.. I have read all night and maybe MS has designed EF for SQL Server, Oracle drivers doesn't seems to map stored procedures quiet natural yet.